# use some excitement in her life

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Not that Lila Mae couldn’t use some excitement in her life, as the two
> men searching her apartment are discovering through items and effects.

I wonder what "use some excitement in her life" means here.

Comment: The phrase 'could use' is American for 'needs' or 'needed'. Not that Lila Mae didn't need some excitement (i.e. she did need some).

Answer (score 1):

'[Someone] could use [something]' is an idiom meaning that they need that thing or would benefit from having it.

'Not that she couldn't' is another way of saying 'she could'.

Evidently the search of Lila Mae's apartment suggests that she leads a dull life.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase shows that Lila Mae *needed some excitement in her life*, whilst the two men searching her apartment are discovering through items and effects.